# I have a custom Address Book field on sales orders for freight bill purposes, but I can't source the full address to a text field in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

We frequently need to have a third address drop down on our sales orders indicating where to send shipping bills. To accomplish this, I have created two custom fields, custbody_vcc_3_p_b_a and custbody_vcc_xtra_add_txt.

The first field is a list/record type tied to the address book. The second is a text area.

I need to filter the first field based on the entity and then have the selected address book record's full address populate into the text area field.

The sourcing & filtering tab in the address book field is no good, it will not allow me to filter on entity, so I need to filter using script somehow.

As for the sourcing, NetSuite is giving me an error message indicating my address book field is not compatible with the getSubrecord function.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/record'],
 function(record) {
   function fieldChanged(context) {
     var subrec = currentRecord.getSubrecord({
              fieldId: 'custbody_vcc_3_p_b_a' //address book field
});

var address = subrec.getValue({
    fieldId: 'address' //I've also tried addrtext
});

if (recordfieldname === 'custbody_vcc_3_p_b_a') 

currentRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: 'custbody_vcc_xtra_add_txt',
    value: address
});
};

return {

 fieldChanged: fieldChanged,

 };
 });
```

The error is SSS_INVALID_FIELD_ON_SUBRECORD_OPERATION. When I tried the script as a 1.0 API as a user event script the error was similar, but more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to copy the text of the address selected in custbody_vcc_3_p_b_a into your text area (custbody_vcc_xtra_add_txt)?

try

```
var address = subrec.getValue({
    fieldId: 'shipaddress' 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had a chance to try this as I started work on another issue while this one was put on pause. I'll update once I had a change to plug it in.